# Import Range function - How to reference a tab name that changes daily

Tags: google-sheets

Every day, the google sheet I'm trying to import from, has a new tab automatically created with the current day's date as the title of the tab. How do I reference that new tab, every day, to import from?

I haven't tried anything beyond manually updating the import range function with the new tab name every day.

=IMPORTRANGE("doc address","11/6/22!D2:E2")

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO OP'S COMMENT**

Turns out the workaround was simpler than I thought.  Instead of using NOW(), you can use TODAY():

```
=IMPORTRANGE("doc address", TEXT(TODAY(), "m/d/y") & "!D2:E2")
```

Presumably this works because TODAY will give the same value all day long, while NOW will give a new value anytime the sheet is updated.  That is just a guess as to why the one is disallowed and the other isn't.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER LEFT FOR REFERENCE**

I've never tried, but I assume you can just dynamically generate the sheet name argument to IMPORTRANGE with the current date.  You seem to be using m/d/y format.  So something like this.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("doc address", TEXT(NOW(), "m/d/y") & "!D2:E2")
```

Here, `NOW` returns the current datetime and TEXT formats it to the desired format. Let me know if that worked for you.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER TO WORKAROUND THE NOW() FUNCTION**

---

*This was my original workaround for the disallowed NOW function, using apps script.  However, it seems that while NOW is not allowed, TODAY is perfectly fine.  Leaving this just in case.*

It seems that certain functions in Google Sheets can't reference non-deterministic functions (like NOW(), RAND(), etc), and IMPORTRANGE is one of them.  It might seem like cheating, but you can duplicate the functionality of NOW() in a custom script and use that instead.

So open the apps script editor and add a function something like this:

```
function getCurrDate() {
  return new Date();
}
```

which will simply create a new Date object and pass it back, and now we can just replace NOW() in my original answer with this new function:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("doc address", TEXT(getCurrDate(), "m/d/y") & "!D2:E2")
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) is the documentation on apps script in case you're not familiar, and I've excerpted the relevant part below:

> **Creating a custom function**
>
> To write a custom function:
>
> 1. Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> 2. Select the menu item Extensions > Apps Script.
> 3. Delete any code in the script editor. For the DOUBLE function above, simply copy and paste the code into the script editor.
> 4. At the top, click Save.
>
> Now you can use the custom function.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if it works for you.

---

Comment: @lee so did this work for you?